# Ensuring a location is not read from and written to at the same time with OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have a variable that is being written to in an OpenMP parallel for loop. The loop is such that no other thread will write to it, but they all read from it at various times. According to some SO answers, reading from and writing to a location at the same time may cause the read value to be corrupted. Is this true? How do I ensure this does not happen while maintaining as much performance as possible?

I looked at the OpenMP atomic construct in the spec. About `atomic write`, it says:

> The atomic construct with the write clause forces an atomic write of the location designated by x regardless of the native machine word size.

Since I know that only one thread writes to the location, this is not what I need.

For `atomic update`, it says

> Only the read and write of the location designated by x are
>   performed mutually atomically.

Does this mean that reads will not overlap with writes? If that's true, I think that's what I need. In that case, can I use `atomic update` on a statement like `x = expr;` (rather than `x += expr;`)?

Could anyone help clarify what exactly `atomic update` does, and/or what I should be using in my case?

I read [Is OpenMP atomic write needed if other threads read only the shared data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612143/is-openmp-atomic-write-needed-if-other-threads-read-only-the-shared-data), but it's not clear to me from there.

EDIT:
@Zulan's answer makes it clear what `atomic update` does, but in my case, I need to protect a read statement from a write to the same location done from *elsewhere* in the code. I don't need to protect the write from other writes (atomic write) as no other threads write to the location, and I don't need to protect read from read. How can I do that?

EDIT2: I understand I may not have been clear. So a code snippet. What I have is an "asynchronous" iteration. When I read a location in the array `x` below, I only need an uncorrupted value; it may have been updated or not any number of times.

```
double *x;

#pragma omp parallel for default(shared)
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof_x; i++)
{
  int j = some_func1(i);
  int k = some_func2(i);
  double temp = some_const*x[j] + x[k];
  x[i] = temp;
}
```

Here, I don't need an atomic write for `x[i]` as it's only written to by one thread, and I don't want atomic reads for `x[j]` and `x[k]`, as simultaneous reads are no problem. But I want to ensure that when I read `x[j]` or `x[k]`, it's not being written to in that very clock cycle by another thread. Is this something I need to care about (which I think it is), and if yes, what to do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to address your specific question, but the general advise of [the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41614045/620382) holds.

> According to some SO answers, reading from and writing to a location at the same time may cause the read value to be corrupted.

Yes. Whether it does or not in practice, highly depends on the architecture, datatype, compiler, optimizations.

> How do I ensure this does not happen while maintaining as much performance as possible?

The portable and clean way to ensure that, is to use atomic read, write and updates (and captures) on all accesses to the variable.

> Does this mean that reads will not overlap with writes? Could anyone help clarify what exactly atomic update does, and/or what I should be using in my case?

No. `atomic update` is not applicable to pure assignments. It is only applicable to statements that read the value, perform an operation on it and write it again. The atomicity of update refers to the read/write of that particular statement, not any other read elsewhere in the code. You should be using `atomic write` for the assignment, and `atomic read` for all other reads of that location.

I hope that clarifies your particular questions. Again, note that atomicity does not guarantee visibility of memory updates. If you rely on eventually seeing the updated value on other threads, you must also consider explicit or implicit memory flushes.

IMHO the OpenMP standard is very well written. If you want the most exact wording, you should refer to it (1.4 and 2.13.6).

Edit: Regarding your specific example, you need to protect **each and every read and write** to `x`. A concurrent read and write to one location is a data race and can result in indeterminate values. From the standard:

> 2.13.6 atomic Construct
>
> [...] To avoid race conditions, all accesses of the locations designated by x that could potentially occur in parallel must be protected with an atomic construct.

Imagine that reading/writing to x is implemented by two separate read/writes. This is explicitly allowed by the standard (1.4.1, "A single access to a variable may be implemented with multiple load or store instructions"):

```
x_j.low  = laod x[j].low;
x_j.high = load x[j].high;
x_k.low  = load x[k].low;
x_k.high = load x[k].high;
temp = some_const * x_j + x_k;
store x[i].low = temp.low;
store x[i].high = temp.high;
```

Now imagine a concurrent situation:

```
Thread 0 [i = 10]             | Thread 1 [j = 10]
----------------------------------------------------------
store x[10].low = temp.low;   |
                              | x_j.low = load x[10].low
                              | x_j.high = load x[10].high
store x[10].high = temp.high; |
```

You cannot prevent reading a corrupted value with only locking either of the thread, you have to do it on both sides.

Note this is only an illustration. For some types in practice there may very well be no difference at all between atomic and non-atomic code. But the standard requires to you so.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense and makes things clearer.

Comment: In my case, I need to protect a read statement from a write to the same location done from *elsewhere* in the code. I don't need to protect the write from other writes (atomic write) as no other threads *write* to the location, and I don't need to protect read from read. I don't get how to do that. What do you think?

Comment: Both the write and the read have to be atomic. You cannot just protect one side, you have to take care of both!

Comment: But.. as long as the location is not being written to, I want to allow simultaneous reads by multiple threads. That's the issue.

Comment: If you don't write the the location concurrently, no need for atomics. I am a bit confused by your notion of "a write to the same location done from elsewhere in the code". What do you mean by elsewhere then?

Comment: @AdityaKashi Again, every access, read and write, needs to be atomic. I added an explanation why to my answer. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

here is a textbook definition from Parallel Programming in OpenMP, 2001, by Chandra,Dagum,Kohr,Mayden,McDonald,Menon.

> The atomic directive is designed to give efficient access to machine primitives/instructions (compare-exchange CMPXCHG on intel X86) that allow the  processor to perform a read,modify,write operation such as an increment on a memory location all in an atomic fashion.  It uses hardware support to acquire exclusive access to a single location for the duration of the update.
>
> the atomic directive, like the critical directive, is **another way of expressing mutual exclusion** and does not provide any additional functionality.  While the critical directive encloses an arbitrary block of code, atomic can be applied only if the critical section consists of a single assignment statement that updates a scalar variable.
>
> the restrictions on the use of the atomic directive ensure the assignment can be translated into a sequence of machine instructions to atomically read, modify, and write the specified memory location.
>   **Concerning synchronization the user must ensure that all conflicting accesses to this memory location are consistently protected using the same synchronization directive (either atomic or critical).**
>
> a critical section containing a single assignment statement using the atomic directive is usually more efficient, and never worse.  but a critical section with multiple assignments cannot be transformed to use a single atomic directive, it requires an atomic directive for each statement- assuming each statement meets the requirement for using the atomic directive.
>   general guidance is to use atomic when updating either a single location or just a few, and to use the critical directive when updating many.

With that said, so far you have identified your assignment statement where you write to some memory location and you are using the atomic directive on that.  You then need to use the atomic directive every where else so that in all other threads that will do a read on that memory location, that read assignment has the atomic directive.  And by everywhere else, the scope of everywhere is what would be a critical section (not critical directive) of code where the parallelism is happening up until the point all threads synchronize.